# Designate groups of consecutive equal values in an ordered dataset

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I'm trying to get the output to look like below. The problem is that I can't do a first_value or RANK because when I partition by event and order by time, then it doesn't break them up in that order. I need them to order by time first and then partition each time.

[image]

Comment: Please show example input, example output and the query that you have tried to solve your problem.

Comment: So I would have rows Event and Time and need to figure outhow to get Desired Row Number. I've tried:
SELECT event, time, ROW_NUMBER () OVER( PARITITON BY event ORDER BY time ASC) as rn
FROM TABLE

But that just puts all the events in order, there's no way to have it be a unique one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### One of the known solutions

Use `lag()` to mark rows when `event` changes and cumulative `sum()` to designate groups, e.g.:

```
with my_table(event, time) as (
values 
    ('A', '12:01'),
    ('A', '12:02'),
    ('B', '12:03'),
    ('A', '12:04'),
    ('A', '12:05'),
    ('B', '12:06'),
    ('B', '12:07'),
    ('A', '12:08')
)

select 
    event, 
    time, 
    sum(change) over (order by time) as "desired row number"
from (
    select 
        event, 
        time, 
        (event is distinct from lag(event) over (order by time))::int as change
    from my_table
    ) s

 event | time  | desired row number 
-------+-------+--------------------
 A     | 12:01 |                  1
 A     | 12:02 |                  1
 B     | 12:03 |                  2
 A     | 12:04 |                  3
 A     | 12:05 |                  3
 B     | 12:06 |                  4
 B     | 12:07 |                  4
 A     | 12:08 |                  5
(8 rows)
```

### Custom aggregate

It would be nice to have the function:

```
select *, group_number(event) over (order by time)
from my_table;
```

This can be done with the custom aggregate:

```
create type group_number_internal as (number int, lag text);

create or replace function group_number_transition(group_number_internal, anyelement)
returns group_number_internal language sql strict as $$
    select 
        case 
            when $2::text is distinct from $1.lag then $1.number+ 1 
            else $1.number 
        end, 
        $2::text
$$;

create or replace function group_number_final(group_number_internal)
returns int language sql as $$
    select $1.number
$$;

create aggregate group_number(anyelement) (
    sfunc = group_number_transition,
    stype = group_number_internal,
    finalfunc = group_number_final,
    initcond = '(0, null)'
);
```

[Test it in rextester.](https://rextester.com/QPOS6252)